# Convert a property file to abstract class

Tags: maven, spring-boot, properties, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I Have a property file sqlqueries.properties.
I want an abstract class to be generated during the build/packaging in spring boot application.

**sqlqueries.properties**

SELECT_QUERY=SELECT * from EMPLOYEE

**SqlQueries.java**

```
    public abstract class SqlQueries {

      public static final String SELECT_QUERY;

 static {
    SELECT_QUERY="SELECT * from EMPLOYEE";
  }

}
```

I came across the similar implementation in one of the source code with the comment

```
/** Generated by maven-utils-plugin:convertProperties */
```

Am not able to figure it out , how to do the same kind for my project

Comment: If you have a spring boot app why are you having sql queries in a properties file? Either you can use jdbc templates / or maybe spring-data (hibernate?) or a like?

Comment: Why are you storing SQL queries in Abstract class? Because, you could directly use the queries on hibernate level (or JPA repositories etc.).

Comment: @khmarbaise
The native query is using certain inbuilt functions which varies with each relational database. The query should not be changed anytime after packaging.
We provide this as a solution to the partner and they should use the appropriate built in functions of their relational database.

Comment: @RaufAgayev : The reason is stated in the above comment